# Dynamics of ideal gas during free expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, navier-stokes

I would like to compute (even numerically) the time evolution of the density profile of an ideal gas which undergoes free expansion.
For concreteness, let's imagine an infinite cylinder with the axis oriented as the $x$ axis, and let the gas be contained by some walls within the region $0<x<x_0$. At time $t=0$, the wall at $x=x_0$ is removed, and the gas is free to expand along the $x$ direction.
I want to determine the function $n(x,t)$, the density profile over time.

My idea is to use Navier-Stokes equation for a non-viscous and compressible fluid, along with the continuity equation. The former reads (in absence of gravity or other external fields)
$$
n \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + n v \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial P}{\partial x},
$$
where $v(x,t)$ is the ($x$ component of the) velocity profile and $P(x,t)$ is the pressure profile.
The latter equation instead is
$$
\frac{\partial n}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (n v) = 0.
$$

Now in my opinion I need one more step to solve this problem, because I have three fields but only two equations, and in particular I would need a third equation that relates pressure to density by exploiting some thermodynamic property of the ideal gas.
If this statement is correct, then what is such equation?

In case of a quasi-static and adiabatic expansion, I imagine something like $P(x,t) \propto n(x,t)^{\gamma}$, where $\gamma$ is the adiabatic coefficient of the gas (is this correct?).
However, as stated at the beginning, I am thinking about a free expansion, which is *not* quasi-static: what is the third equation then?

I have searched a little bit on the forum, but I didn't really find this specific question, so hopefully this is not a duplicate.
Thank you in andvance for any help! :)

Comment: It is invalid to assume an inviscid fluid in free expansion because viscous dissipation is such a critical part of what is happening in this situation (even in the ideal gas limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adiabatic process equation in local form ( for any point in the gas) *is* applicable as the simplest model here, at least until the equations themselves predict something diverges. It assumes there is no heat transfer by conduction, which is idealization just the same as assuming viscosity is zero.

We can regard the first stages of the expansion process as quasistatic for any small pocket of gas, even if the expansion is very quick from a human viewpoint, because all local variables accurately describe state of the gas at least for some time.

The process would not be quasistatic, if at some point of space local state of the gas was not described accurately by continuous functions $n,P,v$. For example, if some discontinuity (like shock wave) appears. In your scenario, in the simplest case, we can assume this does not happen, at least not for some time after the wall removal. In reality, discontinuities can happen if there are strong energy sources (explosion, quake, etc).

Another problem with this kind of model of gas is that after some time, the gas will get so rarified that real gas will stop interacting with itself, while the Stokes equation assumes interaction continues for any value of $n$. For very dilute gas, the model breaks down.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very thorough and useful answer. So as long as shock waves, explosions etc. are absent, I can safely use $P(x,t) = k n(x,t)^{\gamma}$ where $k$ is a constant that I can determine from the initial conditions, right? Something like $k=P_0 V_0^{\gamma}$, where $P_0$ and $V_0$ are initial pressure and volume

Comment: Yes that's a reasonable approach. Well at least it's a valid way to start studies of such system, until the solutions begin to show puzzling or unphysical behaviour. When you understand this simplified model, you can add complications that bring it closer to real life - transport phenomena (heat conduction, viscosity, loss of interaction for too dilute gas, etc.)